# Королевская свита может быть... именитой?

Tags: словосочетания, выбор-слов

> Королева любила охоту, и её выезд отличался пунктуальностью. А вот
>   некий знакомец, проживающий в столь знатном доме, не раз запаздывал
>   присоединиться к именитой свите.

Королева - Кристина, столь знатный дом - вилла Медичи... Рим.

Смущают словосочетания:

*выезд отличался пунктуальностью,*

*проживающий в столь знатном доме,*

*запаздывал присоединиться,*

*к именитой свите.*

Убедите меня, пожалуйста, что я просто чипляюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Убедите меня, пожалуйста, что я просто чипляюсь""

**Скорее всего, да.** Мне не удалось исправить ни одного слова. Хотела заменить наречие  "столь" наречием "весьма", но семантика может измениться: **весьма знатный** ― это очень знатный по виду, **столь знатный** ― очень знатный и хорошо известный окружающим.

Королева любила охоту, и её выезд отличался **пунктуальностью**. А вот некий знакомец, проживающий в **столь** знатном доме, не раз **запаздывал** присоединиться к именитой свите.

Из словаря:

**ПУНКТУАЛЬНЫЙ**,  2. Осуществляемый с крайней аккуратностью, точностью. П-ое следование регламенту.

**ЗАПОЗДАТЬ**, 2. с чем или с инф. Сделать что-л. позже, чем надо. З. ответить.

**СТОЛЬ**,  1. **Книжн**. В такой степени, настолько, так. Почему ты пришёл с. поздно?  Она с. красива, что немудрено влюбиться.

Из современной прессы: Однако в экономической сфере их положение выглядит **не столь радужным**. С чем связано **столь высокое** доверие государства к ним?

Долго я смотрел на Машу, которая, лежа на сундуке, утирала слёзы своей косынкой, и, всячески стараясь изменять свой взгляд на Василья, я хотел найти ту точку зрения, с которой он мог казаться ей **столь привлекательным.** [Л. Н. Толстой. Отрочество (1854)]

**Дополнение** (про именитую свиту)

Именитая свита, по всей вероятности, состоит из именитых людей. Из современных текстов: По словам организаторов, его главное отличие в том, что несмотря **на именитое жюри,** главный судья конкурса — зритель.

**ИМЕНИТЫЙ,** 1. Занимающий высокое общественное положение, почтенный. И. дворянин. И. род. И. человек. И. гость.

Comment: Хотелось бы ещё увидеть рассуждения или примеры, собственно, по поводу ОСНОВНОГО  вопроса: "Королевская свита может быть… именитой?"  Как-то он "проскочился".

Comment: На мой взгляд, есть существенная разница между именитым клубом и именитым коллективом с одной стороны и именитой свитой с другой. Именитый клуб и коллектив имениты сами по себе (обладатели известного имени), они могут состоять из не именитых людей, а именитая свита - это группа, состоящая из именитых людей. Я привел "именитый состав" как пример, близкий по смыслу к "именитой свите".

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, я внесла изменение в ответ. А именитое жюри подходит в качестве примера?

Comment: Думаю, именитое жюри подходит. Обычно жюри - временно собравшаяся группа людей, то есть имениты члены группы, а не группа как некая единица.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не "чипляетесь".

**Пунктуальность** — черта характера **человека**, подразумевающая чрезвычайную аккуратность, систематическое следование правилам.
*Выезд* - не человек; подходящее слово - неукоснительность (устар.).

**Столь** - то же, что **настолько**; используется для крайней степени усиления следующего за ним наречия или прилагательного, часто употребляется с союзом что.
*Проживающий в настолько знатном доме* [что] - в таком виде не подходит.
Возможно: проживающий в столь знатном доме, что мог себе позволить запаздывать...

**Запаздывать** - являться позже, чем надо, задерживаться с приходом.
Считаю, что глагол "присоединиться" здесь лишний.

**Свита** - постоянные спутники особ **царствующей фамилии** и некоторых знатных или высокопоставленных лиц.
Свита королевы Кристины не могла состоять из обычных, "простых" сопровождающих. Она (свита) была *именитой* по определению (если только знакомец не бывал раньше в свите менее знатной особы; они же Медичи! - вот и кочуют из одной свиты, поплоше, в другую, попрестижнее).

В итоге у меня получилось (как вариант):

***Королева любила охоту, и её выезд отличался неукоснительностью. А вот некий знакомец, проживающий в очень (необычайно, весьма) знатном доме, не раз запаздывал  к [именитой] свите.***

Answer (score 1):

На вижу ошибок.

Может ли свита быть именитой? Я думаю - да. В смысле "состоящей из именитых персон". Мне не удалось найти примеров в Нацкорпусе, но Google дает более 6 тыс. результатов для слов "именитый состав", а это похожий случай.

У меня были сомнения по поводу "**знатного дома**". Насколько я знаю, "знатный" в смысле "знаменитый" и в смысле "принадлежащий к знати" уместно лишь по отношению к людям. Но в Нацкорпусе много примеров со словами "знатный дом" - значит, это допустимо.